# Binding data to a ComboBox and then showing ValueMember in another TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mvp

I have a `comboBox` and a `TextBox` in the `View` and when the view is loaded, the `ComboBox` should be populated. After that when a user selects particular item from the `ComboBox`, its related `ValueMember` should be displayed in the `TextBox`.

The View doesn't know about DAL or Presenter and, it only has properties and events.

**VIEW**

```
public partial class frmBankAccount : Form, IBankAccountView
{

    public event EventHandler OnLoadEmployees;

    public BindingSource LoadingEmployees
    {
        set { cmbName.DataSource = value; cmbName.DisplayMember = "Name"; cmbName.ValueMember = "Emp_ID"; }
    } 

    private void frmBankAccount_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         OnLoadEmployees(sender, e);
    }

    private void cmbName_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtEID.Text = cmbName.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }

}
```

When the event fires, Presenter gets a DataTable from DataService and binds it to the ComboBox through the property.

**PRESENTER**

```
class BankAccountPresenter : BasePresenter
{
    public BankAccountPresenter(IBankAccount model, IBankAccountView view, IDataService dataService )  
    {
        _DataService = dataService;
        _Model = model;
        _View = view;

        this.WireUpViewEvents(); 
    }

    private void WireUpViewEvents() 
    {
        _View.OnLoadEmployees += new EventHandler(_View_OnLoadEmployees);
    }

    private void _View_OnLoadEmployees(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadEmployeeNames();
    }

    private void LoadEmployeeNames()
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = _DataService.LoadEmplyees(); //DataService returns a DataTabel with "Emp_ID" and "Name"
        _View.LoadingEmployees = bs;    
    }

    //Main window will call this method to load the View
    public void Show()
    {
        _View.ShowDialog();
    }

}
```

**NOTE:** When populating `ComboBox` since I need only two fields (`Emp_ID` and `Name`), The DataService returns a `DataTable` instead of the `Model` as the model has about 10 other fields as well. The `Model` will be used in subsequent tasks like Search, Insert, Update etc.

Could you please review this code and provide your feedback? You may give your attention to the way that I've used properties to set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` of the Combo. If there is anything which is not acceptable kindly let me know with an alternate solution.

Comment: Unless you are supporting some 10 years old project, you should consider switching to wpf. Winforms is an obsolete framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks pretty clean. As far as I can tell, you have a good separation of concerns. Everything is properly cased and your functions have verb-noun names. All good things.

The only nitpick I have is the `bs` variable. I'm not a fan of ultra short names of any kind. You could call it `source` or some such thing. Seriously though, that's a huge nitpick. I just couldn't find anything else to comment on.